# Keep getting Runtime exception at 0x004000a8: address out of range 0x10400004

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

*I can not seem to find the solution to fix the code in my chkvar (lb   $t3, tokArray+0($s5)) and keep getting the error: line 77: Runtime exception at 0x004000a8: address out of range 0x10400004

Go: execution terminated with errors.*

```
.data
saveReg:    .word   0:10                # extra register space!
#NULL or 0 in tokArray prematurely terminates dumping
#tokArray.Use blanks instead.
TOKEN:      .word   0x20202020:3            # 2-word TOKEN & its TYPE
tokArray:   .word   0x20202020:60           # initializing with blanks
inBuf:      .space  80
space:      .asciiz     "             "
st_prompt:  .asciiz "Enter a new input line. \n"
st_error:   .asciiz "An error has occurred. \n" 
tableHead:  .asciiz "  TOKEN        TYPE\n"
error:      .asciiz "Double Definition Error"
hex:        .asciiz "0x"
symTab: .word   0:40
tableHeader:    .asciiz "Token              Value          Status     \n"
dash:       .asciiz "---------------------------------------------\n"
tempNewLine:    .asciiz "\n"
    .text
#######################################################################
#
#Main
#
#read an input line
#call scanner driver
#clear buffers
#
#Global Registers
#$t5 : index to inBuf in bytes
#$s0 : char type, T
#$s1 : next state Qx
#$s3 : index to the new char space in TOKEN
#$a3 : index to tokArray in 12 bytes per entry
#
######################################################################

    li  $s4, 0x400      # LOC in $s4
    li  $t7, 0          # symTab index
newline:
    jal getline         # get a new input string
    
    li  $t5,0           # $t5: index to inBuf
    li  $a3,0           # $a3: index to tokArray

#State table driver
    la  $s1, Q0         # initial state Q0
driver: lw  $s2, 0($s1)     # get the action routine
    jalr    $v1, $s2        # execute the action

    sll $s0, $s0, 2     # compute byte offset of T
    add $s1, $s1, $s0       # locate the next state
    la  $s1, ($s1)
    lw  $s1, ($s1)      # next State in $s1
    sra $s0, $s0, 2     # reset $s0 for T
    b   driver          # go to the next state

dump:   
    lb  $t3, tokArray       # if the first token is # exit
    beq $t3, 0x23, exit
    li  $s5, 0          # index to tokArray[][]
nextTok:
    lb  $t3, tokArray+12($s5)
    bne $t3, ':', operator  # check if next token is colon
    lw  $t4, tokArray+0($s5)    # get current token
    sw  $t4, TOKEN
    lw  $t4, tokArray+4($s5)
    sw  $t4, TOKEN+4
    li  $s6, 1          # DEFN = $s6 = 1
    jal VARIABLE
    addi    $s5, $s5, 24        # skip next token: �:�
operator:
    addi    $s5, $s5, 12        # get next token index
    li  $s7, 1          # $s7 = isComma = true
chkVar:
#lw $t3, tokArray + 8($s5)
#beq $t3, 6, realDump #type is 6 �#� then dump
    lb  $t3, tokArray+0($s5)
    beq $t3, '#', realDump
    bne $s7, 1, nextVar     # not comma or type is not 2
    lb  $t3, tokArray+10($s5)   # TESTESSTDSERS
    subi    $t3, $t3, 0x30
    bne $t3, 2, nextVar
    lw  $t4, tokArray+0($s5)    # get current token
    sw  $t4, TOKEN
    lw  $t4, tokArray+4($s5)
    sw  $t4, TOKEN+4
    li  $s6, 0          # DEFN = $s6 = 0
    jal VARIABLE        # call VARIABLE function
nextVar:
    lb  $t3, tokArray+0($s5)    # check if token is �,�
    beq $t3, 0x2C, yes
    bne $t3, 0x2C, no
yes:
    li  $s7, 1
    j   after
no:
    li  $s7, 0
    j   after
after:
    addi    $s5, $s5, 12        # get next token index
    b   chkVar          # check next token
realDump:
    jal clearInBuf      # clear input buffer
    jal clearTokArray       # clear token array
    jal clearTok
    jal printsymTab
    addi    $s4, $s4, 4     # LOC +=4
    b   newline         # ask for next input line
exit:
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
VARIABLE:
    sw  $ra, saveReg        # +0 = $ra
    jal srchSymTab      # symIndex = $t8
    bge $t8, $zero, else
    li  $s0, 0x4
    or  $t9, $s0, $s6       # newStatus = $t9
    jal saveSymTab
    b   varEnd
else:
    sw  $t2, saveReg+4      # $t2 = oldStatus
    lw  $t2, symTab+12($t8)
    and $t9, $t2, 0x2
    and $t2, $t2, 0x1
    sll $t2, $t2, 1
    or  $t9, $t9, $t2
    or  $t9, $t9, $s6
    sw  $t9, symTab+12($t8)
    lw  $t2, saveReg+4  
varEnd:
    b   realEnd
varRealEnd: 
    lw  $ra, saveReg
    jr  $ra
    
saveSymTab:
    sw  $t9, symTab+12($t7)
    sw  $t2, saveReg+4
    lw  $t2, TOKEN
    sw  $t2, symTab+0($t7)
    lw  $t2, TOKEN+4
    sw  $t2, symTab+4($t7)
    add $t8, $zero, $t7
    addi    $t7, $t7, 16
    lw  $t2, saveReg+4
    jr  $ra
printsymTab:
    sw  $t2, saveReg+8
    sw  $t3, saveReg+12
    sw  $t4, saveReg+16
    sw  $t5, saveReg+20
    li  $t2, 0
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, tableHeader        # load header
    syscall
    la  $a0, dash           # load dashes
    syscall
repeat:
    beq     $t2, $t7, ret
    la  $t3, symTab($t2)
    lb  $t4, symTab+8($t2)
    li  $t5, '\0'
    sb  $t5, symTab+8($t2)
    move    $a0, $t3
    syscall
    sb  $t4, symTab+8($t2)
    addi    $t2, $t2, 8
    la  $a0, space
    syscall
    li  $v0, 1
    lw  $a0, symTab($t2)
    addi    $t2, $t2, 4
    syscall
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, space
    syscall
    la  $a0, hex
    syscall
    li  $v0, 1
    lw  $a0, symTab($t2)
    addi    $t2, $t2, 4
    syscall
    li  $v0, 4      
    la  $a0, tempNewLine
    syscall
    bc1f    repeat
ret:
    lw  $t2, saveReg+8
    lw  $t3, saveReg+12
    lw  $t4, saveReg+16
    lw  $t5, saveReg+20
    jr  $ra
realEnd:    
    la $s0, symACTS     # load address of symACTS to access the first line
    sll $t9, $t9, 2     # newStatus * 8
    add $s0, $s0, $t9   # calculate the address of the correct symACT
    sra $t9, $t9, 2 
    jr $s0
symACTS:
    b symACT0
    b symACT1
    b symACT2
    b symACT3
    b symACT4
    b symACT5
    
symACT0:
    lw  $t1, symTab+8($t8)
    sw  $s4, symTab+8($t8)
    b   varRealEnd
symACT1:
    lw  $t1, symTab+8($t8)
    sw  $s4, symTab+8($t8)
    b   varRealEnd
symACT2:
    lw  $t1, symTab+8($t8)
    b   varRealEnd
symACT3:
    la  $a0, error
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    li  $t1, -1
    b   varRealEnd
symACT4:
    sw  $s4, symTab+8($t8)
    li  $t1, -1
    b   varRealEnd
symACT5:
    sw  $s4, symTab+8($t8)
    li  $t1, 0
    b   varRealEnd
srchSymTab:
    sw  $t2, saveReg+4
    sw  $t3, saveReg+8
    sw  $t4, saveReg+12
    li  $t2, 0              # i index
    li  $t8, -1
startSearch:    
    bge $t2, $t7, srchEnd
    lw  $t3, TOKEN
    lw  $t4, symTab($t2)
    bne $t3, $t4, update
    lw  $t3, TOKEN+4
    lw  $t4, symTab+4($t2)
    bne $t3, $t4, update
    add $t8, $zero, $t2
    j   srchEnd
update:
    addi    $t2, $t2, 16
    b   startSearch
srchEnd:
    lw  $t2, saveReg+4
    lw  $t3, saveReg+8
    lw  $t4, saveReg+12
    jr  $ra
####################### STATE ACTION ROUTINES #####################
###################################################################
#
#ACT1:
#$t5 : Get next char
#T = char type
#
##############################################
ACT1: 
    lb  $a0, inBuf($t5)         # $a0: next char
    jal lin_search          # $s0: T (char type)
    addi    $t5, $t5, 1         # $t5++
    jr  $v1
    


###############################################
#
#ACT2:
#save char to TOKEN for the first time
#save char type as Token type
#set remaining token space
#
##############################################


  ACT2:
        li  $s3, 0              # initialize index to TOKEN char 
        sb  $a0, TOKEN($s3)         # save 1st char to TOKEN
        addi    $t0, $s0, 0x30          # T in ASCII
        sb  $t0, TOKEN+10($s3)      # save T as Token type
        li  $t0, '\n'
        sb  $t0, TOKEN+11($s3)      # NULL to terminate an entry
        addi    $s3, $s3, 1
        jr  $v1
        
#############################################
#
#ACT3:
#collect char to TOKEN
#update remaining token space
#
#############################################
ACT3:
    bgt $s3, 7, lenError        # TOKEN length error
    sb  $a0, TOKEN($s3)         # save char to TOKEN
    addi    $s3, $s3, 1         # $s3: index to TOKEN
    jr  $v1 
lenError:
    li  $s0, 7              # T=7 for token length error
    jr  $v1
                    
#############################################
#
#ACT4:
#move TOKEN to tokArray
#
############################################
ACT4:
    lw  $t0, TOKEN($0)          # get 1st word of TOKEN
    sw  $t0, tokArray($a3)      # save 1st word to tokArray
    lw  $t0, TOKEN+4($0)        # get 2nd word of TOKEN
    sw  $t0, tokArray+4($a3)        # save 2nd word to tokArray
    lw  $t0, TOKEN+8($0)        # get Token Type
    sw  $t0, tokArray+8($a3)        # save Token Type to tokArray
    addi    $a3, $a3, 12            # update index to tokArray
    
    jal clearTok            # clear 3-word TOKEN
    jr  $v1

############################################
#
#RETURN:
#End of the input string
#
############################################
RETURN:
    sw  $zero, tokArray($a3)        # force NULL into tokArray
    b   dump                # leave the state table


#############################################
#
#ERROR:
#Error statement and quit
#
############################################
ERROR:
    la  $a0, st_error           # print error occurrence
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    b   dump


############################### BOOK-KEEPING FUNCTIONS #########################
#############################################
#
#clearTok:
#clear 3 - word TOKEN after copying it to tokArray
#
#############################################
clearTok:
    li  $t1, 0x20202020
    sw  $t1, TOKEN($0)
    sw  $t1, TOKEN+4($0)
    sw  $t1, TOKEN+8($0)
    jr  $ra
    
#############################################
#
#printline:
#Echo print input string
#
#############################################
printline:
    la  $a0, inBuf          # input Buffer address
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    jr  $ra

#############################################
#
#printTokArray:
#print Token array header
#print each token entry
#
#############################################
printTokArray:
    la  $a0, tableHead          # table heading
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    la  $a0, tokArray           # print tokArray
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    jr  $ra

############################################
#
#clearInBuf:
#clear inbox
#
############################################
clearInBuf:
    li  $t0,0
loopInB:
    bge $t0, 80, doneInB
    sw  $zero, inBuf($t0)       # clear inBuf to 0x0
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4
    b   loopInB
doneInB:
    jr  $ra
    
###########################################
#
#clearTokArray:
#clear Token Array
#
###########################################
clearTokArray:
    li  $t0, 0
    li  $t1, 0x20202020         # intialized with blanks
loopCTok:
    bge $t0, $a3, doneCTok
    sw  $t1, tokArray($t0)      # clear
    sw  $t1, tokArray+4($t0)        #  3-word entry
    sw  $t1, tokArray+8($t0)        #  in tokArray
    addi    $t0, $t0, 12
    b   loopCTok
doneCTok:
    jr  $ra
    

###################################################################
#
#getline:
#get input string into inbox
#
###################################################################
getline: 
    la  $a0, st_prompt          # Prompt to enter a new line
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    la  $a0, inBuf          # read a new line
    li  $a1, 80 
    li  $v0, 8
    syscall
    jr  $ra


##################################################################
#
#lin_search:
#Linear search of Tabchar
#
#$a0 : char key
#$s0 : char type, T
#
#################################################################
lin_search:
    li  $t0,0               # index to Tabchar
    li  $s0, 7              # return value, type T
loopSrch:
    lb  $t1, Tabchar($t0)
    beq $t1, 0x7F, charFail
    beq $t1, $a0, charFound
    addi    $t0, $t0, 8
    b   loopSrch

charFound:
    lw  $s0, Tabchar+4($t0)     # return char type
charFail:
    jr  $ra


    
    
    .data

STAB:
Q0:     .word  ACT1
        .word  Q1   # T1
        .word  Q1   # T2
        .word  Q1   # T3
        .word  Q1   # T4
        .word  Q1   # T5
        .word  Q1   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q1:     .word  ACT2
        .word  Q2   # T1
        .word  Q5   # T2
        .word  Q3   # T3
        .word  Q3   # T4
        .word  Q0   # T5
        .word  Q4   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q2:     .word  ACT1
        .word  Q6   # T1
        .word  Q7   # T2
        .word  Q7   # T3
        .word  Q7   # T4
        .word  Q7   # T5
        .word  Q7   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q3:     .word  ACT4
        .word  Q0   # T1
        .word  Q0   # T2
        .word  Q0   # T3
        .word  Q0   # T4
        .word  Q0   # T5
        .word  Q0   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q4:     .word  ACT4
        .word  Q10  # T1
        .word  Q10  # T2
        .word  Q10  # T3
        .word  Q10  # T4
        .word  Q10  # T5
        .word  Q10  # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q5:     .word  ACT1
        .word  Q8   # T1
        .word  Q8   # T2
        .word  Q9   # T3
        .word  Q9   # T4
        .word  Q9   # T5
        .word  Q9   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q6:     .word  ACT3
        .word  Q2   # T1
        .word  Q2   # T2
        .word  Q2   # T3
        .word  Q2   # T4
        .word  Q2   # T5
        .word  Q2   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q7:     .word  ACT4
        .word  Q1   # T1
        .word  Q1   # T2
        .word  Q1   # T3
        .word  Q1   # T4
        .word  Q1   # T5
        .word  Q1   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q8:     .word  ACT3
        .word  Q5   # T1
        .word  Q5   # T2
        .word  Q5   # T3
        .word  Q5   # T4
        .word  Q5   # T5
        .word  Q5   # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q9:     .word  ACT4
        .word  Q1  # T1
        .word  Q1  # T2
        .word  Q1  # T3
        .word  Q1  # T4
        .word  Q1  # T5
        .word  Q1  # T6
        .word  Q11 # T7

Q10:    .word   RETURN
        .word  Q10  # T1
        .word  Q10  # T2
        .word  Q10  # T3
        .word  Q10  # T4
        .word  Q10  # T5
        .word  Q10  # T6
        .word  Q11  # T7

Q11:    .word  ERROR 
    .word  Q4  # T1
    .word  Q4  # T2
    .word  Q4  # T3
    .word  Q4  # T4
    .word  Q4  # T5
    .word  Q4  # T6
    .word  Q4  # T7
    
    
Tabchar: 
    .word ' ', 5
    .word '#', 6
    .word '$', 4 
    .word '(', 4
    .word ')', 4 
    .word '*', 3 
    .word '+', 3 
    .word ',', 4 
    .word '-', 3 
    .word '.', 4 
    .word '/', 3 

    .word '0', 1
    .word '1', 1 
    .word '2', 1 
    .word '3', 1 
    .word '4', 1 
    .word '5', 1 
    .word '6', 1 
    .word '7', 1 
    .word '8', 1 
    .word '9', 1 

    .word ':', 4 

    .word 'A', 2
    .word 'B', 2 
    .word 'C', 2 
    .word 'D', 2 
    .word 'E', 2 
    .word 'F', 2 
    .word 'G', 2 
    .word 'H', 2 
    .word 'I', 2 
    .word 'J', 2 
    .word 'K', 2
    .word 'L', 2 
    .word 'M', 2 
    .word 'N', 2 
    .word 'O', 2 
    .word 'P', 2 
    .word 'Q', 2 
    .word 'R', 2 
    .word 'S', 2 
    .word 'T', 2 
    .word 'U', 2
    .word 'V', 2 
    .word 'W', 2 
    .word 'X', 2 
    .word 'Y', 2
    .word 'Z', 2

    .word 'a', 2 
    .word 'b', 2 
    .word 'c', 2 
    .word 'd', 2 
    .word 'e', 2 
    .word 'f', 2 
    .word 'g', 2 
    .word 'h', 2 
    .word 'i', 2 
    .word 'j', 2 
    .word 'k', 2
    .word 'l', 2 
    .word 'm', 2 
    .word 'n', 2 
    .word 'o', 2 
    .word 'p', 2 
    .word 'q', 2 
    .word 'r', 2 
    .word 's', 2 
    .word 't', 2 
    .word 'u', 2
    .word 'v', 2 
    .word 'w', 2 
    .word 'x', 2 
    .word 'y', 2
    .word 'z', 2

    .word 0x7F, 0
```

Comment: So, what is the value of `$s5` when the crash happens, and how did it end up with that value?

Comment: this is the value at $s5 when it crashes: 0x00000003

Comment: What I'm seeing is that there's an infinite loop and `$s5` goes up by 12 each iteration.  Eventually, it becomes 0x3effd0, which when added to the base of the array, becomes 0x10400004, which is just outside the allowed address map for global data as 0x10400000 is the heap base address.

Comment: sorry, I am new to mips, how can modify my code so that this error is fixed?

Comment: Just like any programming language, stop the loop at the right time.